# returning multiple values from functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a js file (below) where each function returns 2 results (Step1 and Step2).  I need to put these results into a format like...

"Mix " + (Step1 productType) + " with " + (Step1 peroxide) + ". " + (Step1 timing)

Using a " + (Step2 productType) + " , mix " + (Step2 toneCalc) + ", with " + (Step2 peroxide) + ". " + (Step2 timing)

What is the best way to get these results into the formats above?
I know how to do a single value, but not quite sure on multiple functions wrapped in a function.

Thanks

```
function doubleprocess(type) {

   function productType() {
    var step1;
    var step2;
    if (type == "light") {
        step1 = "lightner";
        step2 = "demi-color";
    } else {
        step1 = "demi-color";
        step2 = "demi-color";
    }
    return step1, step2;
   }


   function toneCalc() {
    var step1;
    var step2;

    if (type == "light") {
        step1 = "light gold";
    } else if (type == "dark") {
        step1 = "80% gold with 20% red"
    } else {
        step1 = "another tone";
    }

    step2 = "neutral";

    return step1, step2;
   }

   function peroxide() {
    var step1;
    var step2;

    if (type == "light") {
        step1 == "20V/6% peroxide";
    } else if (type == "dark") {
        step1 = "something else";
    } else {
        step1 = "Do something.";
    }
    step2 = "Do something else.";
    return step1, step2;
   }

   function level() {
    var step1 = "";
    var step2;

    if (type == "dark") {
        step1 = "Do something.";
    } else {
        step1 = "Do Nothing.";
    };

    step2 = "Do something.";

    return step1, step2;
   }

   function timing() {
    var step1;
    var step2;
    if (type == "light") {
        step1 == "Do something.";
        step2 = "Do something.";
    } else if (type == "dark") {
        step1 = "Do something.";
        step2 = "Do something.";
    } else {
        step1 = "Do something.";
        step2 = "Do something.";
    }
     return step1, step2;
   }
 }
```

Comment: return them as an object? return { step1: step1, step2: step2 };

Comment: I'm going to have to agree, I think ... object is the route to go.  Your question needs a bit of clarity.  Are you looking to return both objects with the function or the strings you defined above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return multiple variables from a function. However you could return an object.

```
function peroxide() {
    var step1;
    var step2;

    if (type == "light") {
        step1 == "20V/6% peroxide";
    } else if (type == "dark") {
        step1 = "something else";
    } else {
        step1 = "Do something.";
    }
    step2 = "Do something else.";
    var rtn = new Object();
    rtn.step1 = step1;
    rtn.step2 = step2;
    return rtn;
   }
```

Comment: That's an array though.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't use the `obj = { key: value }` format but ok.

Comment: /I just did it so you have something to complain about. Nah I just like to type more chars. (notice I abbreviated "Characters")

Comment: great, I will return an object from each function, but now how do I call and get the function to fill.., 

"Mix " + (Step1 productType) + " with " + (Step1 peroxide) + ". " + (Step1 timing)

Using a " + (Step2 productType) + " , mix " + (Step2 toneCalc) + ", with " + (Step2 peroxide) + ". " + (Step2 timing)

Comment: Sheri, you can add 'var peroxide = peroxide();' then o 'peroxide.step1' and 'peroxide.step2' to fill

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions only return a single value. Try returning an object or array.